# Uploading file by label tag in capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, capybara

I have problem uploading file by using capybara and cucumber.

The HTML is the following

```
<div class="dyn-crm-upload-btn-container">
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="visible: newCrmBtnEnabled, enabled: fileEditEnabled">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
      <span data-bind="i18n:panels.partnerCrm.new" data-i18n="panels.partnerCrm.new">NEW</span> 
      <input id="dyn-crm-file-input" class="dyn-crm-upload-btn" type="file" name="file" accept=".csv" data-bind="events: { change: setFileToNewName }"></label>
</div>
```

And if I have manualy choosed a file, the HTML is following in a new div

```
    <div data-bind="visible: fileUploadVisible" class="dyn-crm-file-upload" style="">
<input type="text" data-bind="value: fileToUpload.name, i18n:[placeholder]panels.partnerCrm.fileUpload.enterName" maxlength="20" class="k-textbox dyn-crm-filename" id="dynCrmFilename" data-value-update="keyup" data-i18n="[placeholder]panels.partnerCrm.fileUpload.enterName" placeholder="File name"> 
<input type="button" data-bind="click: uploadFileCrmFile,i18n:[value]panels.partnerCrm.fileUpload.upload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" data-i18n="[value]panels.partnerCrm.fileUpload.upload"><div class="file-upload-progress-container">
</div>
```

I have tried this

```
attach_file(find('file',:visible=>false),File.absolute_path('C:/Users/user/test.csv'))
```

And this

```
attach_file('file',File.absolute_path('C:/Users/user/test.csv'))
```

And some other variations, but I get the following error

```
 Unable to find file field "file"
```

Or when using id

```
 Unable to find file field "dyn-crm-file-input"
```

Also I have tried to execute some scripts before attach_file upload.

I'm using

```
cucumber 2.1.0
ruby 2.1.6
nokogiri 1.6.6.2
capybara 2.4.4
selenium-webdriver 2.47.1
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDITED**

Here is the link for the css picture:
[css picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2VWD.png).

Comment: can you please share the css properties of your input file? like this http://oi64.tinypic.com/345dfld.jpg

Comment: Added the css  to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I imagined, you will have to use jQuery to change the `display:none` of your element to `display:block`, for example.

To achieve tis, you can try with this just before attaching the file:

```
page.execute_script("$('.dyn-crm-upload-btn-container').css('display','block')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara generally can't call attach_file on a non visible file input.  To work around this you need to use #execute_script to  modify the file inputs css so it becomes visible on the page and then use attach_file on it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10582484)

Comment: @praveenSharma this does provide the answer - use execute_script to adjust the css so the element is visible. It doesn't provide the exact code (since the css wasn't in the question when I answered) but exact code isn't needed for it to be a valid answer